# My kotlin spring boot project loading to much time and not compiling?I

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, gradle

I am developing a spring boot Kotlin project with IntelliJ idea when I run the project it is running to taking more than 20 minutes and still building.

I am using Java jdk 17 corretto version and my machine is Windows 10

spring boot running for more than 20 minutes and still loading.

[image]

Comment: It's not still loading. The `bootRun` Gradle task runs as long as the application is running. It finished starting 20 minutes ago.

Comment: thats good comment what do you think it is taking to much time

Comment: :facepalm: **it is running the application**

Comment: yes but why not showing output then I am digging from morning

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @DavidMakogon thank you for your suggestion I want to explain my problem thats why upload

Comment: @DavidMakogon In this case, the image is the reason we know what the problem was. If they didn't upload the image, it would be impossible to guess what the problem was.

Comment: @CLOVIS - where, on that image, can I see that something is running for 20+ minutes? And how does that help solve any problem? Note: there's no programming question here, and no debugging info.

Comment: @DavidMakogon If you want  I can add my gradle files as well

Comment: @DavidMakogon bottom left, "`:bootRun 20min 57s`". See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Gradle, each "action" the build system needs to take is called a "task". Tasks can do anything: compilation, but also running the application.

Looking at the bottom left of your screenshot, you can see the list of tasks executed:

- `compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE`: this means you changed no Kotlin code, so in 1s 410ms Gradle noticed no code needed to be compiled.
- `compileJava SKIPPED`: the icon means the task was skipped. Most likely, it's because there is no Java code in your project.
- `processResources UP-TO-DATE`: Gradle collects all files in `src/main/resources` and puts them in the final binary.
- `classes UP-TO-DATE`: is a lifecycle task to group the previous ones.
- …
- `bootRun`: This task is running your application. It is not compilation. It's been running for 20min 57s, which means Gradle finished compiling ~21 minutes ago. Your application is running, it's not compiling anymore.

In total, compilation took around 2 seconds (`compileKotlin` + `processAot` + `compileAotJava`), which is normal. Your application is running normally, you just didn't notice it :)